# I can't understand to solve the question (Khan Academy Algebra Basics - Exponent Properties)

Tags: rational-functions

I was learning (practicing to solve) simplifying the rational expressions.
I know how to simplify the rational expressions... but I can't understand some part of the questions.

[The question that I can't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCXip.png)

If you look at this image, you could see sentence "First, let's set the denominator equal to zero and solve for n:", and there is "Select all that apply." too.

But, there was no any explanations about it must be denominator = 0.
I found it just in hint, not a basic question..

So... why solving equation and suppose that denominator = 0 are related to simplifying the rational expressions?

And why we suppose denominator = 0 and we don't touch numerator..?

Is there any mathematical relationships between them?

I hope you (expert) will answer to my question, thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that division by zero is undefined for real numbers?  You can answer questions like "What is $\frac{5}{2}$?" and "What is $\frac{1}{8}$?", but something like $\frac{6}{0}$ doesn't make sense.  Even $\frac{0}{0}$ doesn't make sense.  It is for that reason that we figure out when the denominator is zero since we want to make sure not to forget that a rational expression didn't make sense at those points.  It is possible that after simplifications, the "not making sense" aspect is forgotten.  We don't check the numerator for being zero since $\frac{0}{4}$ is fine.

Comment: Did you forget that "Which values of $n$ make the expression undefined" was part of the question?

Comment: Akiva Weinbergerm, Maybe I forgot that... thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that division by $0$ is undefined. Thus, before we begin simplifying an expression, we want to know when it is undefined. Remember that $0$ divided by something else is just $0$, so we don't need to worry about the numerator.

For example, the expression $\frac{1+x}{x}$ is undefined at $x=0$, but when $x=-1$, we just get $\frac{0}{-1}=0$.

As another example, consider $\frac{x}{x}$. Clearly this is just equal to $1$. However, the fraction is *still* undefined at $x=0$. That is because $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. To compensate, we can write that $\frac{x}{x}$ is equal to $1$ when $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand them.